# Cómo configurar timezone en codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

En mi aplicación tengo en index.php la siguiente línea

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Bogota');
```

sin embargo, cuando voy a imprimir una fecha ya formateada con `strftime("%d de %B de %Y", $date);` me arroja el resultado en ingles.

También e intentado con `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_CO.UTF-8');` y el resultado es el mismo. Cabe aclarar que mi aplicación está en un hosting compartido y no tengo acceso a php.ini. Agradezco cualquier orientación para poner mi fecha en español.

Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Fecha en Codeigniter

Este proceso solo se necesita si utilizas el `helper` de fechas de `CI`. Tendrás que descargar las traducciones de `codeigniter` y configurar para que aparezca en el idioma que desees.

Puedes encontrar las traducciones en el repositorio oficial de `CI` -> https://github.com/bcit-ci/codeigniter3-translations (No es necesario que descargues todas).

Lo añades a tu proyecto en la carpeta correspondiente y para configurarlo vas a `application/config/config.php`, donde encontrarás:

```
$config['language'] = 'english';
```

Lo modificas por `spanish` y listo.

Además, si quieres cargar esos ficheros de idioma automáticamente en todo el proyecto hay que añadirlo al autoload (solamente los ficheros que hay dentro de la carpeta `spanish` que te interesen, a modo `array` y sin `_lang`):

```
$autoload['language'] = array('date');
```

---

> Fecha en PHP

En caso de utilizar funciones nativas de `PHP` (como es tu caso) tendríamos que:

**Sistemas Windows**

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'spanish');
echo strftime("%d de %B de %Y"); //Ejemplo
```

**Sistemas Unix**

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_CO.UTF-8');
echo strftime("%d de %B de %Y"); //Ejemplo
```

**Mi servidor es compartido y no soporta setlocale**

Si tu servidor no soporta setlocale creo que no lo puedes hacer de manera directa (corregidme si me equivoco), tendrás que crearte una función auxiliar que te ayude a traducir dichas fechas. Ejemplo:

```
function fechaES($fecha){
    $mes = array(
        'January' => 'Enero',
        'February' => 'Febrero',
        'March' => 'Marzo',
        'April' => 'Abril',
        'May' => 'Mayo',
        'June' => 'Junio',
        'July' => 'Julio',
        'August' => 'Agosto',
        'September' => 'Septiembre',
        'October' => 'Octubre',
        'November' => 'Noviembre',
        'December' => 'Diciembre'
    );

    return strtr($fecha, $mes);
}

echo fechaES(strftime('%d de %B de %Y'));
```

Saludos,

Comment: Gracias por responder, hice lo que sugeriste, copié `MY_Lang.php` en la carpeta core, `date_lang.php` en la carpeta `language/spanish/`. El archivo `config.php` ya tenía la configuración en `spanish` y cargué el lenguaje desde el `autoload`, y aún así no funcionó. El idioma de la fecha se controla con setlocale pero no sé que es lo que estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: El problema es de PHP, no de CI. Edito la respuesta.

Comment: Perfecto, hubo que crear ese helper y empezar a agregar la función donde la necesito, muchas gracias por la orientación (y)